# PHP - Access twitter api response variables

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using the twitter api to get my latest mentions.

Twitter api link: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/mentions_timeline

Function used to get last mentions:

```
function twitter_get_tweets(){
    $connection = $this->twitter_auth();
    $latest_tweet = $connection->get('statuses/mentions_timeline', array('count' => 1));
    return $latest_tweet;
}
```

Preview of response: http://projects.helpful.ninja/twitter/

Sadly im not able to access the variables in there directly, such as the text node.

Example:

```
[text] => @pr0b_ Submit a request to our Support team and they'll be in touch ASAP
```

Been testing something like:

```
$twitter_bot = new twitter_bot_functions($twitter_settings['api_key'], $twitter_settings['api_secret'], $twitter_settings['access_token'], $twitter_settings['access_token_secret']);
$get_latest_mention = $twitter_bot->twitter_get_tweets();
echo $get_latest_mention['text'];
```

Does someone have a idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an array first and then a stdClass object. So you should use it like

`echo $get_latest_mention[0]->text;`

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad. Any more help?